# Modificar el fomato de Json con C# en .Net

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un código que serializa y convierte los campos de una base de datos a `JSON`, a través de `JsonConvert`, y el problema, es que quiero modificar el formato normal de `JSON`, que siga la estructura como en este [vínculo](https://truckingsim.github.io/Ajax-Bootstrap-Select/example/dataset.jsonp.js).

Aqui está la parte de código, pero lo que hace es que genera un `JSON` normal, pero no sé como modificarlo, de acuerdo al vínculo:

**C#**

```
public class DatosCatPuestoGeneral
{
    public List<arrDatosCatPuestoGeneral> DatosCatalogoPuestoGeneral = new List<arrDatosCatPuestoGeneral>();
    public string toJson()
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para tener ese resultado, necesitas una clase con esos campos.

```
class Persona {

   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

Luego debes poblar un Array o List con elementos de dicha clase, por el método que sea.

```
var personas = new ArrayList();
personas.Add(new Persona { Nomre = "Juan", Email = "a@b.com" });
personas.Add(new Persona { Nomre = "Jose", Email = "c@d.com" });
```

Finalmente lo serializas a Json.

```
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personas);
```

Comment: ese metodo de add, lo puedo llenar llamando a una consulta select de sql?

Comment: Si, puedes saber mas sobre ArrayList en la doc. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add(v=vs.110).aspx. Era un ejemplo de como poblarla, pero los datos pueden salir de cualquir lado, no necesitan estar hardcodeados.

Comment: disculpa, no podrias poner un codigo ejemplo de como hacerlo con la consulta con un sqlcommand, es que no me queda claro como hacerlo

Comment: por ejempllo,  tengo esta linea de codigo:   claseDatosCatPuestoGeneral.DatosCatalogoPuestoGeneral.Add(clasearrDatosCatPuestoGeneral);                                                                       que llama a todos los datos de la consulta, pero no se como modificarlos como dices

Comment: no se si me explique bien?

Comment: Aparte, no entinedo como lo modifica al formato que esta en el vinculo de la descripcion, eso no seria un json normal?

Comment: Gillermo, el vinculo usa JSON-P. Que es una forma de transferencia, para evitar el problema causado por la Politica del Mismo Origen. Si necesitas que el resultado sea JSON-P, esta respuesta no es correcta. Quiza debas actualizar la pregunta y explicar que tipo de resultado quieres.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificarlo utilizando las librerías de [Newtonsoft para .Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Un ejemplo sería la siguiente forma:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ClaseParaSerializar);
JObject datosParaModificarEnElJson = JObject.Parse(json);
datosParaModificarEnElJson["TransaccionId"] = 123456;
JObject objeto = (JObject)datosParaModificarEnElJson["datosParaModificarEnElJson"];
objeto.Remove("AlgunosDatosParaEliminar");
json = datosParaModificarEnElJson.ToString();
```

Puedes acceder directamente a los nodos del Json y a partir de ahí modificar los valores y nuevamente volver a serializar el Json